# Jquery .load() is not loading html properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

When i am loading an html file with .load() function of jquery, then it will not load the whole html like :

**Instead of this :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link .. />
        <script .. />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>..</div>
        <div>..</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**It loads this :**

```
<link .. />

<div>..</div>
<div>..</div>
```

Can anybody tell me why and what can i do if i want to load whole html?

Comment: RTFM :D - It's not jQuery which dismisses these elements its the browser - [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - _During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser._

Comment: If you're trying to pull in `html`, `head`, and `body` elements into the DOM via AJAX, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Are you

1. loading the jquery first in the head
2. loading in the document ready state
3. have you checked the div name to make sure you are right
4. use firebug on Firefox as it will show you what is being returned or an error
5. using load where html is needed

Your code in the head after you have linked jquery should be something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mydivforcontent').load("theforeignpage"); // you may need to replace load with html
});
```

Comment: You're not really answering the question... at all actually.

Comment: remember that loading with AJAX will not load the head but only the body (or a particular aspect of the page)